# Oracle PL/SQL Tokenize String with empty position

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a String like this:

AAA,BBB,,DDD

And i would like to tokenize it using comma and retrieve a table like this:

```
VALUE  LEVEL 
AAA    1
BBB    2
(null) 3
DDD    4
```

I need to know the String and in witch position i found it, without missing null String.

I've tried a code like this but i miss the empty position:

```
SELECT    regexp_substr ('AAA,BBB,,DDD', '[^,]+', 1, level), level
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace ('AAA,BBB,,DDD', '[^,]+'));
```

The output is this:

```
VALUE LEVEL
AAA   1
BBB   2
DDD   3
```

Comment: what is the output of the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple answer is that replacing comma`(,)` by space with comma`(, )`  like below

```
SELECT    trim(regexp_substr (replace('AAA,BBB,,DDD',',',', '), '[^,]+', 1, level)), level
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (replace('AAA,BBB,,DDD',',',', '), '[^,]+');
```

this also works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b255d/26

Comment: With this you lost the last string DDD

Comment: thats happens because length of commas,hence i have made an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT token, lvl FROM (
  SELECT    regexp_substr ('AAA,BBB,,DDD', '[^,]*', 1, LEVEL) token, LEVEL lvl,
            lag(regexp_substr ('AAA,BBB,,DDD', '[^,]*', 1, LEVEL)) over(order by level) prev_token
  FROM    dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace ('AAA,BBB,,DDD', '[^,]+'))*2
) WHERE prev_token is null;
```

Comment: That would not give the correct position of the tokens.

Comment: Right @LalitKumarB , i've seen that the Token is correct but isnt correct the lvel. I get 1, 3, 5, 6 and not 1, 2, 3, 4 (or 0, 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 1):

in oracle 11g and upper you can do something like this query:

```
with      
  tab1(pointer,test,split_test) as
  (select
    1 as pointer,test,substr(test,0,case when instr(test,',',1,1) = 0 then LENGTH(test)
                        else instr(test,',',1,1)-1 end) split_test from table1
  union all
  select
  pointer + 1 as pointer,test,
  substr(test,instr(test,',',1,pointer) + 1,case when instr(test,',',1,pointer + 1) = 0 then LENGTH(test) else
   instr(test,',',1,pointer + 1) - instr(test,',',1,pointer) - 1 end) split_test
  from tab1 where pointer - 1 < LENGTH(test)-LENGTH(REPLACE(test,',','')))
select split_test as "value",pointer as "level" from tab1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3897/8)